# how to multiply and divide a numpy array's each sub numpy array with two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to multiply and divide a numpy array's each sub numpy array with two numpy arrays.

I have a numpy array `x` with shape `[100, 5]`, two numpy arrays `y` and `y` both with shape `(5,)`.

I am trying to change the value of the tensor: 
For each sub numpy array `w` along with axis=0 in `x`, it should have shape `[1, 5]`, I want to do `(w - y)*z`.

My thought was to for-loop over `x` and pick each sub array inside it to do this and then reconstruct the original array. However, this may be not efficient.

Comment: So, you want the ith column in x to have y[i] subtracted from it, and then multiplied by z[i]?

Comment: Yeah, it is, thanks.

Comment: Simply do : `(x - y)*z`?

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, but I am not sure if this is correct. I am not very familiar with numpy.

Comment: This should help with familiarity - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
(x - y) * z
```

sample:

```
>>> x.shape,y.shape, z.shape
((10L, 5L), (5L,), (5L,))
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])
>>> y
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> z
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> (x-y)*z
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  5,  10,  15,  20,  25],
       [ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50],
       [ 15,  30,  45,  60,  75],
       [ 20,  40,  60,  80, 100],
       [ 25,  50,  75, 100, 125],
       [ 30,  60,  90, 120, 150],
       [ 35,  70, 105, 140, 175],
       [ 40,  80, 120, 160, 200],
       [ 45,  90, 135, 180, 225]])
```